# Run a function that connects to a websocket server within a flask app

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-restful

I am trying to accomplish two things. 1: Connect to a websocket server and listen for events. 2. Create endpoints for a static webpage. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do both simultaneously. If I run the connect_to_obs function by itself it works just fine. I can get all the events from the server but If I cannot figure out how to run it together with flask. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code for my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, jsonify, make_response, Response, send_from_directory, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import os
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from functions import createFolder, fileHandler, update_obs_settings, get_profile_image, get_obs_settings, searchCategories, validateAccessToken, checkCredentials, createTags, storeTokenResponse, init_db, getAccessTokenFromDb, store_user_data
from OBSConnection import connect_to_obs
import time
import json
import requests
import threading
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

init_db()

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = uploadFolder


t = threading.Thread(target=connect_to_obs)
t.start()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# main driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=connect_to_obs)
    t.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my connect_to_obs function:

```
def connect_to_obs():
    obs_url, obs_port, obs_password = get_obs_settings()
    if obs_url != None or obs_port != None:
        parameters = simpleobsws.IdentificationParameters() # Create an IdentificationParameters object
        parameters.eventSubscriptions = None # Subscribe to the General and Scenes categories
        print(f'{obs_url}:{obs_port} password: {obs_password}')
        ws = simpleobsws.WebSocketClient(url=f'ws://{obs_url}:{obs_port}', password=obs_password) # Every possible argument has been passed, but none are required. See lib code for defaults.

        async def onReplayBufferSave(eventType, eventData):
            if eventType == 'ReplayBufferSaved':
                print(eventData['savedReplayPath'])

        async def onRecordStateChanged(eventType, eventData):
            if eventType == 'RecordStateChanged':
                print(eventData['outputPath'])

        async def init():
            global obsConnection
            while True:
                try:
                    await ws.connect()
                    await ws.wait_until_identified()
                    ws.register_event_callback(onReplayBufferSave)
                    ws.register_event_callback(onRecordStateChanged)
                    print('Connected to OBS Websocket')
                    obsConnection = True
                    break
                except:
                    print("Connection failed, attempting to reconnect in 5 seconds...")
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(init())
        loop.run_forever()
    else:
        print("Please set up OBS settings in the settings page.")
        exit()
```

Comment: You are starting TWO `connect_to_obs` threads.  Was that your intention?

Comment: No that is not my intention but it still didnt work even taking away the first thread.

Comment: Mixing async and threading can be tricky, although your usage seems simple enough.  There are some articles that talk about it.